# How do I keep the date-format from Excel when importing a time series in R?

Tags: r, excel, date, time-series, finance

When I import a financial time series from Excel to R, the dates turn into integers. Each column represents a date.
I understand that Excel converted them to a form where they represent the number of days since the origin date of 01/01/1900.
How can I turn these numbers back into 'normal' dates in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use one of these functions:

```
xlsnum_to_POSIXct <- function(n)
{
    as.POSIXct(
       x = n*24*60*60,
       origin = "1900-01-01 00:00:00"
    );
}

xlsnum_to_POSIXlt <- function(n)
{
    as.POSIXlt(
       x = n*24*60*60,
       origin = "1900-01-01 00:00:00"
    );
}
```

which converts the number of days into number of seconds since 1900/01/01, and wraps it conveniently into an R date-time type.

Should work also with fractions of day, vectors of day counts etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can change data type from integer to date using function `as.Date` and setting a date origin.

If your dataset is called `df` and your column with the dates is called `event_date`, for example:

```
df$event_date <- as.Date(df$event_date, origin = "1899-12-30")
```

Or, using `mutate` from package `dplyr`:

```
df <- mutate(df, event_date = as.Date(event_date, origin = "1899-12-30"))
```

Comment: thank you! I have more than 5000 columns however (or rows if I transpose), any idea how I can change their data types simultaneously?

Comment: It's also not the values in the columns, but the column names themselves that are currently integers and should become dates. I probably didn't specify that well enough.

Comment: What type of data do those columns contain? It would be helpful if you could edit your question to include a sample of your dataframe. For example, using data.frame(id = 1:3, 10012000 = c(5, 7, 12), 11012000 = c(8, 17, 2)) - or a screenshot if easier.

Comment: My impression is that you will first need to reshape your dataframe into a long format, and then us as.Date() on the new date column.